# Adding a button to the config page

Tags: shopware6

Is there a way to add a button to the config page of a Shopware 6 plugin? The button should call an external api to see if the given api-key is valid?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a custom component for config fields. You'll have to register the component and add the config field using the `component` element and with the name of the component.

```xml
<!-- config.xml -->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shopware/platform/trunk/src/Core/System/SystemConfig/Schema/config.xsd">

    <card>
        <title>Api configuration</title>
        <component name="custom-config-component">
            <name>apiKey</name>
        </component>
    </card>
</config>
```

```js
import template from './custom-config-component.html.twig';

const { Component } = Shopware;

Component.register('custom-config-component', {
    template,

    props: {
        value: {
            required: true,
        },
    },

    methods: {
        onChange(value) {
            this.$emit('change', value || '');
        },

        onInput(value) {
            this.$emit('input', value);
        },

        onClick() {
            const apiKey = this.value;
            // send the request with the api-key
        },
    },
});
```

```html
<!-- custom-config-component.html.twig -->
<div class="custom-config-component">
    <sw-text-field
        v-model="value"
        label="Api-Key"
        size="medium"
        required
        @input="onInput"
        @change="onChange"
    />
    <sw-button
        @click="onClick"
    >
        Verify Api-Key
    </sw-button>
</div>
```